# How to detect file content change?

Tags: java, file, encryption, md5

I would like to create a component to detect the file being modified before process. The file contains a JSON object.

Is this the right way to detect the file modification based on file size value? 
Below is the flow:

1. Get the file size.
2. Encrypt it with MD5 algorithm, say it generated us encrypted value "0123sdf".
3. Avoid the user modifying the file content. Before file process, we take the file and do the encryption with MD5 again, if it returns the value "0123sdf", then we are sure it doesn't have modification.

My questions:

1. Is it the right approach to detect file modification?
2. What the library advise to use or using `java.security.DigestInputStream` will do?

Comment: Are you using java 7? If so, have you looked at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html ?

Comment: Are you needing to detect modification only while your application is running? Or do you need to detect modification between invocations of your application?

Comment: This is the right approach *in general*. Where do you intend to store hash values? How is the original file being used (for example, your software generates the file but the file is stored on the user side and later you need to verify that it is in the same state)?

Comment: intend to store it under the filename, will take the hash value from the filename and recheck it matching, does it make sense ?